# Real time QR scanner for windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, qr-code, zxing

Is there any **real time QR code scanner** library available for windows phone 8.1 ?

I tried ZXing.net and Zxing.Net.Mobile, not success. Please share any sample source code.

Thanks,
Snober

Comment: I have succesfully implemented solutions using ZXing.net. What have you tried? ©

Comment: I tried with Zxing.Net in windows phone 8.1 with real time scanning. Am not able to do it. Can you please share some sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NokiaImagingSDK` to and analyze the preview frames with `ZXing.net`. I have a sample on Github: https://github.com/igorkulman/QRReader.WPA81